# angular.js:xxxx Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cookiesServiceProvider <- cookiesService

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the following error from angular.js library. How can i debug the below console error?

```
angular.js:12477 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cookiesServiceProvider <- cookiesService <- CatalogViewController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=cookiesServiceProvider%20%3C-ookiesService%20%3C-%20CatalogViewController
    at http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:68:12
    at http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4289:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4437:39)
    at http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4294:45
    at getService (http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4437:39)
    at invoke (http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4469:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:4486:27)
    at http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:9151:28
    at http://testsite/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js:4018:28
    at invokeLinkFn (http://testsite/Scripts/angular_bootstrap_UI/angular.js:8789:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the cookies part of angular

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-cookies.js

and inject it in your module

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngCookies'])
```

make sure you don't get 404 for the cookies